# Android Recycler returns zero output despite reaching onBindViewHolder() for each row

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I've put a RecyclerView in the 'Tutorial' activity in my application, to list tutorial versions, which come from the Room database my app has. It is hosted within a fragment, but that's of little consequence since I had the same problem before putting it in there. The RecyclerView adapter reaches onBindViewHolder() without any issues and I get logs from the Log.w I used for debugging there with correct data. The problem seems to be that Layout does not get inflated at all, and the buttons that each row is supposed to output never appear.

THE ADAPTER

```
public class VersionListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VersionListAdapter.VersionViewHolder> {

    private List<Version> mVersionList;
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private final OnViewClickListener mListener;

    public VersionListAdapter(Context context)
    {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mVersionList = null;
        this.mListener = (OnViewClickListener) context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public VersionViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_versions_rv, viewGroup, false);
        return new VersionViewHolder(row, mListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VersionViewHolder versionHolder, int rowNumber) {
        versionHolder.thisVersion = mVersionList.get(rowNumber);
        versionHolder.versionButton.setText((mVersionList.get(rowNumber).getText()));
        Log.w("THIS IS A TAG", mVersionList.get(rowNumber).getText()); //correct output
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(mVersionList!=null) return mVersionList.size();
        else return 0;
    }

    public void setElementList(List<Version> versions){
        this.mVersionList = versions;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public static class VersionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        OnViewClickListener listenerForThisRow;
        Version thisVersion;
        Button versionButton;

        public VersionViewHolder(
                @NonNull View viewForThisRow, OnViewClickListener listenerFromActivity)
        {
            super(viewForThisRow);
            this.listenerForThisRow = listenerFromActivity;
            versionButton = viewForThisRow.findViewById(R.id.version_button);
            viewForThisRow.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            listenerForThisRow.onViewClick(thisVersion);
        }
    }

    public interface OnViewClickListener{
        void onViewClick(Version version);
    }
}
```

THE FRAGMENT CLASS WHICH HOSTS THE RECYCLER VIEW

```
public class VersionRecycler extends Fragment {

    protected RecyclerView mRecycler;
    protected VersionListAdapter mAdapter;

    public VersionRecycler(){
        super(R.layout.fragment_recycler_versions);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            @NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {
        VersionViewModel mVersionViewModel = new VersionViewModel(requireActivity().getApplication());
        long tutorialId = requireArguments().getLong("tutorialId");
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler_versions, container, false);
        mAdapter = new VersionListAdapter(requireActivity());
        mRecycler = view.findViewById(R.id.versions_rv);
        mRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        mVersionViewModel.getByTutorialId(tutorialId).observe(requireActivity(), versions->mAdapter.setElementList(versions));
        mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        return view;
    }
}
```

HOW THE FRAGMENT IS EMBEDDED IN THE ACTIVITY

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_versions_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

FRAGMENT LAYOUT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".versionrecycler.VersionRecycler">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/versions_rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/row_versions_rv"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

LAYOUT FOR RECYCLERVIEW ROW

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/version_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also add Start and Bottom constraints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".versionrecycler.VersionRecycler">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/versions_rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

        tools:listitem="@layout/row_versions_rv"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

You could also change RecyclerView layout_height to wrap_content and add Start constraint only

Comment: I added those, sadly it did not result in anything showing up.

Comment: Just noticed other two weird configurations I would change:
* LinearLayout layout_height from 0dp to match_parent (and be sure that the activity has a proper height value)
* Layout for row now has layout_height=match_parent. Change it to wrap_content (or some pre-defined standard height values like 56dp, 72dp etc).

Also it is not a good thing to manually create the ViewModel instance (there's the ViewModelFactory for it) and avoid reassigning your List attribute. Just use a MutableList and invoke clear/addAll methods

Comment: I corrected the layout like you said, nothing still. Something I noticed while debugging: clicking in certain areas of the screen will activate the OnClick listeners each row in the RecyclerView is meant to have. It's like they're there but set to be invisible.